# A couple of basic string parsing functions

Tags: strings, coldfusion, cfml

I have an app that does a fair bit of text-parsing based on free-form user inputs.  In this, I run searches on the whole string, and then on the last value of the string separate from the rest of the string.  Here is a pair of functions I wrote to `getLast` and `getSubString`.

```
<cffunction name="getLast" output="no" returnType="string" access="public" hint="Takes a string and returns the last value by either comma or space, or returns nothing if the string is only one value long">
    <cfargument name="str" required="yes" type="string">

    <cfset var returnVar = "">

    <cfif listLen(arguments.str) GT 1>
        <cfoutput>listLen(#arguments.str#)</cfoutput>
        <cfset returnVar = trim(listLast(arguments.str))>
    <cfelseif listLen(arguments.str, " ") GT 1>
        <cfoutput>listLen(#arguments.str#, " ")</cfoutput>
        <cfset returnVar = trim(listLast(arguments.str, " "))>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn returnVar>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getSubString" output="no" returnType="string" access="public" hint="Takes a string and returns the beginning of the string minus the last value">
    <cfargument name="str" required="yes" type="string">

    <cfset var last = getLast(arguments.str)>
    <cfset var lastLen = len(last) + 1>
    <cfset var thisLen = len(str) - lastLen>
    <cfset var returnVar = str>

    <cfif thisLen GTE 1>
        <cfset returnVar = trim(mid(str, 1, thisLen))>
    </cfif>

    <!--- remove trailing commas --->
    <cfif right(trim(returnVar), 1) IS ",">
        <cfset returnVar = mid(returnVar, 1, len(trim(returnVar)) - 1)>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn returnVar>
</cffunction>
```

And just for fun, some code that was commented out of the second function:

```
<!---
<cfset var listDelim = ",">
<cfset var i = 0>
<cfset var returnVar = "">

<!--- if the string is longer than one value --->
<cfif len(last)>
    <cfif NOT findNoCase(arguments.str, ",")>
        <cfset listDelim = " ">
    </cfif>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#evaluate(listLen(arguments.str, listDelim) - 1)#" index="i">
        <cfset returnVar = "#returnVar# #listGetAt(arguments.str, i, listDelim)#">
    </cfloop>
    <cfset returnVar = trim(returnVar)>
<cfelse>
    <cfset returnVar = arguments.str>
</cfif>
--->
```

Next time I think I'm going to avoid parsing all my own text and just dumping it all into SOLR.

Comment: I didn't look here to see if there are UDFs exactly for this, but before I write UDFs, I always check here: http://cflib.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ColdFusion 9+, you should abandon your vars within functions and move toward using the LOCAL scope.  LOCAL vars do not escape the function.

This:

```
<cfset var last = getLast(arguments.str)>
<cfset var lastLen = len(last) + 1>
<cfset var thisLen = len(str) - lastLen>
<cfset var returnVar = str>
```

Should be:

```
<cfset LOCAL.last = getLast(arguments.str)>
<cfset LOCAL.lastLen = len(LOCAL.last) + 1>
<cfset LOCAL.thisLen = len(LOCAL.str) - LOCAL.lastLen>
<cfset LOCAL.returnVar = str>
```

Comment: Disagree (and it's subjective either way). Actively scoping local variables makes the code more verbose and clunky to read. But mileage varies. I'd not - however - advocate changing existing code from one to the other approach.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old, but just wanted to give some thoughts on your `getSubString()` function:

1. `getLast()` and `lastLen` use:

   ```
   <cfset var last = getLast(arguments.str)>
   <cfset var lastLen = len(last) + 1>
   <cfset var thisLen = len(str) - lastLen>
   <cfset var returnVar = str>
   ```

   - If `str` is just a single word and not a comma- or space-delimited list, your `lastLen` will be 1, and your `thisLen` will now be 1 less than the length of `str`'s value.

     Subsequently, your `returnVar` will just return your `str` without its last character. This may be what you intended, or it may be not...
   - Be consistent in scoping your vars - use `arguments.str` everywhere.
   - I would `trim(arguments.str)` in the 3 lines above where it is used, and drop all the `trim()`s in subsequent lines.
2. Instead of `<cfif thisLen GTE 1>`, which is same as GT 0 in this case, just test for boolean: `<cfif thisLen>`.
3. `<cfset returnVar = trim(mid(str, 1, thisLen))>` - why not just use `left()` function instead: `<cfset returnVar = left(returnVar, thisLen)>`? + use `returnVar` instead of `str` and drop `trim()` if you used it in var setting code.
4. This code block:

   ```
   <cfif right(trim(returnVar), 1) IS ",">
    <cfset returnVar = mid(returnVar, 1, len(trim(returnVar)) - 1)>
   </cfif>
   ```

   should be inside the `<cfif>` block above it - it is only relevant when `thisLen > 0`.  And again, just use `left()` function instead of `mid()` (and drop all `trim()` calls if you changed the var setting lines to use it).
5. To simplify things even more, your two `<cfif>` blocks can be compressed into these 3 lines:

   ```
   <cfif thisLen>
    <cfset returnVar = rereplace(left(returnVar, thisLen), "[\s,]+$", "")>
   </cfif>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Observations:

- `getLast()` is very vaguely named. It looks like you're trying to get the last "word" in a string, so unless `getLast()` is in a CFC called Sentence.cfc or WordList.cfc, I think its name could be improved, eg: `getLastWord()`.
- if you are after getting the last "word" when there's regex support for that, which makes for a much smaller function, and is also more robust in that it uses an accepted definition for what constitutes a "word":

(the editor is ignoring my formatting if I position the code here, for some reason. I've put it at the bottom...)

Or just use `listLast()` with multiple delimiters:

```
listLast(str, ", .");
```

But the regex solution is probably more robust.

I would use a variation of the regex approach above, or just `listDeleteAt()` for the second function. And, again, improve its name.

Code from above:

```
public string function getLastWord(required string str){
    var result = reReplace(str, ".*\W(.+)$", "\1", "ONE");
    result = reReplace(result, "\W", "", "ALL"); // any non-word characters 
    return result;
}
writeOutput(getLastWord("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe ColdFusion already has similar function to your first:
ListLast() - Gets the last item in a list
http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_l_14.html

I would suggest in getSubString that you trim the input when you assign it to 'last', then you can remove the trim()s used later on.

```
<cfset var last = trim(getLast(arguments.str))>
```

Comment: If you look at her getLast(); function you can see that she's making use of ListLast(); her function basically just performs ListLast( x ); and ListLast( x , " " );

Comment: Yeah, my problem with "listLast" is that I'm not sure which delimiter might be required, depending on what the user types in. This is all part of a text parsing routine where a user could type in an address, including spaces and/or commas.

Comment: In fact, now that I think about it, I believe my original solution to this did a loop on characters starting at the right and stopping when it hit a space or a comma.